# How to show $F(s)=s|s|^{p-2}\log|s|$ is locally Lipschitz?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

In a paper I saw this expression:
"*The function* $F:R^*\rightarrow R$  *with*  $F(s)=s|s|^{p-2}\log(|s|), p>1$  *is* *locally Lipschitz*." To show this we have to prove that for any $\rho>0$ there exists a constant $C(\rho)>0$ such that 
$$
|F(s_{1})-F(s_{2})|\leq C(\rho)|s_{1}-s_{2}|,\qquad\forall s_{1}, s_{2}: 0<|s_{1}|,|s_{2}|<\rho.\qquad\qquad (E)
$$
However, the above function isn't differentiable at $s=0$. I think the term $F:R^*\rightarrow R$ means the continuous extension of $F$ at $s=0$ (the paper dosn't say any thing about this notation.) I mean the function
$$
F_1(s)=F(s),\quad for\quad s\neq0;\qquad F_1(s)=0,\quad for\quad s=0.
$$
Easily, we can see $F_{1}$ is differentiable at $s=0$ and $F_1'(0)=0$.

**My Question:**

If my understanding of "*locally Lipschitz*" is true, then how we can show (E) for $F_{1}$? Is it enough to say that *every continuously differentiable function is locally Lipschitz*? (This is a theorem.)

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: @nicomezi Thank you very much. But I think $|F(s)|\rightarrow 0$ as $s\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I read $p<1$, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

'Locally Lipschitz' means Lipschitz in some neighborhood of each point of the domain. If $s \in \mathbb R^{*}=\mathbb  R \setminus \{0\}$ then $s>0$ throughout some neighborhood of $s$ or $s<0$ throughout some neighborhood of $s$. Hence $F$ is continuously differentiable in the neighborhood. By MVT any continuously differentiable function on  a closed interval is Lipschitz. Hence $F$ is locally Lipschtz.

Note that differentiablity at $0$ and inequality (E) are not involved at all in proving this result.

Comment: You answer the question but you do not adress the multiple problems in the OP's reasoning... Not sure that it is very useful.

Comment: @nicomezi I have defined the term 'Locally Lipschtz'. Once OP accepts this definition (E) becomes irrelevant.

Comment: You do not explain why, which is part of the question.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy  Thank you very much. So, the inequality (E) have to be corrected in this form:  For any $s_{0}\in \mathbb{R}^*$ there exists a constant $\rho>0$  such that for all $s_1, s_2$ for which $ |s_1-s_{0}|<\rho,\  |s_2-s_{0}|<\rho $ we have $|F(s_{1})-F(s_{2})|\leq C(\rho)|s_1-s_2|$, for some positive constant $C$ depending on $\rho$. That's right?

Comment: @Albert Yes, that is right.